# How to use Evented IO to wait for a result with await in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

In Rust there are relatively new features, `async` and `await`.

This syntax is a godsend but I am not sure how to use it in an evented i/o pattern in Rust.

One such example of a use is where there are websockets and you send a message and are waiting for a particular message to return, but there is just one `onMessage` and one `sendMessage` for the entire application.

So I have tried to make a Javascript equivalent where I use a `setInterval` to run a clock (to simulate multiple `onMessage` events in the case of websockets.

How would I write this Javascript in Rust/or Tokio?. Again I'm not actually going for this code but going for the conceptual `sendMessage` to a websocket server such that the method call waits a corresponding answer.

```
let setAlarm = (seconds) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) {

        if(seconds > 60 || seconds < 0) {
            return reject(new Error("Invalid seconds"));
        }

        //Represents going through many messages 
        //waiting for the matching id indicating 
        //its a reply to my original message
        let handle = setInterval(function() {
            let date = new Date();
            if(date.getSeconds() == seconds) {
                clearInterval(handle);
                resolve(date);
            }
        }, 1000);

    });
}


async function main() {
    
    //Wait for 45th second
    await setAlam(45);
    console.log("Running tasks now");

}
```

Comment: have u gotten the answer yet? i want to know what is the equivalent of JS 'resolve' in rust